# What are the non JQuery versions of .change() and .toggle()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I convert the JQuery version of this code to non JQuery?

#### JQuery

```
jQuery(function($){
    //change event handler for the checkbox
    $('#isTracefile').change(function(){
        //if it is checked set the select element's container to display else hide
        $('#cttracefile').toggle(this.checked);
        //if it is unchecked set the input element's container to display else hide
        $('#custom').toggle(!this.checked);
    }).change()
})


        <div id="cttracefile">
            Sample Tracefiles to use: 
            <select name="tracefile">
                <option value="capacity.13Mbps_200RTT_PER_0.000001.txt">capacity.13Mbps_200RTT_PER_0.000001</option>
            </select> 
        </div>
        <div id="custom">
            <label>Forward Delay: </label><input id="fd" type="number" min="0" max="1000" step="1" value ="100"/> ms
            <br/>
            <label>Reverse Delay: </label><input id="rd" type="number" min="0" max="1000" step="1" value ="100"/> ms
            <br/>
            <label>Download Capacity: </label><input id="down" type="number" min="1" max="30" step="1" value ="1"/> MBps
            <br/>
            <label>Upload Capacity: </label><input id="up" type="number" min="1" max="30" step="1" value ="1"/> MBps
            <br/>
            <label>Packet Error Rate (PER): </label><input id="per" type="number" min="0.00001" max="1" step="0.00001" value ="0.00001"/>
        </div>
```

What are the non-JQuery versions of `.change()` and `.toggle()`?

Comment: are you talking about using the html `<script>` tag inside the file? that will keep it "all in one file" - jquery is about as "regular" as you can get with javascript

Comment: on your fiddle - you would just take the jquery and copy paste it into index.html like....`<script>*jquery stuff*</script>`

Comment: yes, I can do like that; but I guess jQuery is a big file to copy on my html file. The if-else should not be a big deal to only use jQuery though! I need to do it as a few self-written functions.

Comment: what do you mean..."jquery is a big file to copy"?

Comment: The JS part is on the fiddle. I will edit the question here as well. What should I do then?! I have my own server sending files, and I need to debug and stuff. I want to make the index.html as small as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be used as your non-jquery solution. You would just have to set initial values

```
var isTrace = document.getElementById('isTracefile');
var ctTrace = document.getElementById('cttracefile');
var custom = document.getElementById('custom');

isTrace.onchange = function(){
    if (isTrace.checked) {
        ctTrace.style.display = "none";
        custom.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        custom.style.display = "none";
        ctTrace.style.display = "block";
    }
};
```

Demo fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/adjit/3at2c/4/

Comment: Fair enough! Thanks. Actually the checkbox should be the other way around, but that wasonly a matter of adding "!" ;) thanks.

Comment: If you don't wait for the page to load, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'onchange' of null`, also you've not triggered it the first time (although that is a pretty easy addition to the way you've written it)

Comment: @Adjit Wondering why it does not work on my browser, Opera, IE. This should not be a special thing...

Comment: @TinaJasmin most likely has something to do with Paul S. comment above. Make sure the page is loaded before running the script, otherwise the retrieval of elements can return null if that element has not been loaded yet

Comment: @Adjit I changed some parts and applied `document.onload`, but no changes. Do you know of any ways to fix it?

Comment: @TinaJasmin well, it is hard for me to tell exactly why it isn't working without seeing the code. You should post a new question and detail how you implemented your JS code. Then comment with a link to the new question, this way other people can help as well.

Comment: @Adjit ok...will do now.

Comment: @TinaJasmin also, why do you need to consolidate the files into 1?

Comment: @Adjit because I've built a test server, and am sending the index.html html contents to the client. Sending several files makes both my server code and the index.html more complicated. I want to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: @TinaJasmin well, if your server is a webserver then you can just put files into your webserver and then pull them client-side by accessing the url to those certain files. Like for my company, our website is metsales.com, and that is based on our webserver. Now when your browser builds the site I have folders like `images` etc.. so I would pull it by setting the source link of whatever it is `<img>` tags, or `href` or `src` to something like `https://www.metsales.com/images/thisimage.jpg`... something like that. Our test server was set up the same way

Comment: Right. I know that, but for my testing purposes, it is not very good to send a big JQuery file. Anyways, here is my other problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273665/my-html-get-method-does-not-show-all-form-inputs

Answer (score 0):

- `$(fn)` becomes `window.addEventListener('load', fn)`
- `$('#id')` becomes `document.getElementById('id')`
- `$jqo.change(fn)` becomes `element.addEventListener('change', fn)`
- changing visibility based on a bool `element.style.display = bool ? '' : 'none'`

Finally, you trigger a `change` event on your *Node*, this is a bit more complicated to do in vanilla depending on browsers you want to support, but you can use `element.dispatchEvent` with `new Event(type)`.

So all together,

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    document.getElementById('isTracefile')
        .addEventListener('change', function () {
            document.getElementById('cttracefile')
                .style.display = this.checked ? '' : 'none';
            document.getElementById('custom')
                .style.display = !this.checked ? '' : 'none';
        });
    document.getElementById('isTracefile').dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
});
```