# My HTML "Get" method does not show all form inputs

Tags: html, forms

I have a html form, which I need to parse the information on the server side (which is a simple HTTP Java server I have written) so to run a program with those options. Unfortunately when I submit the form, it does not include all the input options, and only shows a subset of them, e.g. `/run.html?-z=-w&yse=yse1&tracefile=capacity.1Mbps_c50.txt`. There are other form items (such as number boxes `fd`, `rd`, `per`, etc) which are not included. Can someone help me with that? (actually the ones which are not included should be `visible`, unless the `Use a sample tracefile` checkbox is checked).

You can see the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/3at2c/10/

Here is the whole HTML code (remember, if you want to modify the JavaScript, please do not use JQuery; everything should be written in a single file)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var isTrace = document.getElementById('isTracefile');
var ctTrace = document.getElementById('cttracefile');
var custom = document.getElementById('custom');
isTrace.onchange = function(){
    if (!isTrace.checked) {
        ctTrace.style.display = "none";
        custom.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        custom.style.display = "none";
        ctTrace.style.display = "block";
    }
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
    <h3>Please select a configuration below to run the emulator with:</h3>
    <form action="run.html" method="GET">
        <input type="checkbox" name="-w" value="-w"/>[-w]: wrap around at tracefile end and begin anew at time zero./
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="-z" value="-w"/>[-z]: zero packets routed through; route to co-resident webserver  
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="-b" value="-b"/>[-b]: run the emulator in the background.
        <br/>

        <br/> YSE Emulator to Run: <select name="yse">
        <option value="yse1">YSE1</option>
        <option value="yse2">YSE2</option>
        <option value="yse3">YSE3</option>
        <option value="yse4">YSE4</option>
        <option value="yse5">YSE5</option>
        <option value="yse6">YSE6</option>      
        </select> <br/> 
        <br/>        
        <input type="checkbox" id="isTracefile" checked />Use a sample tracefile
        <!--Wrap the select and its label in a container so that it can be shown/hidden-->
        <div id="cttracefile">
            Sample Tracefiles to use: 
            <select name="tracefile">
                <option value="capacity.1Mbps_c50.txt">capacity.1Mbps_c50</option>
                <option value="capacity.3Mbps_100RTT_PER_0.00001.txt">capacity.3Mbps_100RTT_PER_0.00001</option>
                <option value="capacity.3Mbps_100RTT_PER_0.0001.txt">capacity.3Mbps_100RTT_PER_0.0001</option>
                <option value="capacity.3Mbps_100RTT_PER_0.001.txt">capacity.3Mbps_100RTT_PER_0.001</option>
                <option value="capacity.3Mbps_100RTT_PER_0.01.txt">capacity.3Mbps_100RTT_PER_0.01</option>
                <option value="capacity.3Mbps_100RTT_PER_0.05.txt">capacity.3Mbps_100RTT_PER_0.05</option>
                <option value="capacity.3Mbps_100RTT_PER_0.1.txt">capacity.3Mbps_100RTT_PER_0.1</option>
                <option value="capacity.3Mbps_200RTT_PER_0.0001.txt">capacity.3Mbps_200RTT_PER_0.0001</option>
                <option value="capacity.3Mbps_200RTT_PER_0.001.txt">capacity.3Mbps_200RTT_PER_0.001</option>
                <option value="capacity.3Mbps_400RTT_PER_0.0001.txt">capacity.3Mbps_400RTT_PER_0.0001</option>
                <option value="capacity.3Mbps_400RTT_PER_0.001.txt">capacity.3Mbps_400RTT_PER_0.001</option>
                <option value="capacity.13Mbps_200RTT_PER_0.000001.txt">capacity.13Mbps_200RTT_PER_0.000001</option>
            </select> 
        </div>
        <!--Wrap the custom inputs and its labels in a container so that it can be shown/hidden-->
        <div id="custom">
            <label>Forward Delay: </label><input id="fd" type="number" min="0" max="1000" step="1" value ="100"/> ms
            <br/>
            <label>Reverse Delay: </label><input id="rd" type="number" min="0" max="1000" step="1" value ="100"/> ms
            <br/>
            <label>Download Capacity: </label><input id="down" type="number" min="1" max="30" step="1" value ="1"/> MBps
            <br/>
            <label>Upload Capacity: </label><input id="up" type="number" min="1" max="30" step="1" value ="1"/> MBps
            <br/>
            <label>Packet Error Rate (PER): </label><input id="per" type="number" min="0.00001" max="1" step="0.00001" value ="0.00001"/>
        </div>

        <br/> <input type="submit" value="Run Emulator!"/>
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Only fields with a `name` will be sent to server. Just add a `name` to each field you want to post (even same as `id`) and you'll be done. For example: `<input id="fd" name="fd" type="number" ...`

Comment: oh, I see! There is a problem with the checkbox; when it is selected, the others should be hidden. It works on Fiddle, but when you test it on your browser, it does not work. Can you help with that as well?

Comment: Pretty common error: your script is parsed and executed BEFORE your HTML (because it's...before it). At that moment HTML hasn't been parsed then elements you're searching with `getElementById()` don't exist and event `changed` won't be attached to anything (you should also see an error in browser console). Just move `<script>` block after your HTML (for example before you close `</body>`) and it'll work. In jsFiddle it works because script is triggered as it was after html.